Why do I keep getting the past transactions with geyser?
I built geyser plugin with a no-voting validator, everything works fine, node catched up itself, but when I "tail -f" the log file, the geyser keep streaming to me the "notify_transaction V0_0_2" data, all of the data is from 2 hours ago! why? Shouldn't geyser stream to me the latest transaction data?
I use https://github.com/mwrites/solana-geyser-plugin-scaffold as my geyser plugin,
here is notify_transaction defines:
fn notify_transaction(
        &self,
        transaction: ReplicaTransactionInfoVersions<'_>,
        slot: u64,
    ) -> solana_geyser_plugin_interface::geyser_plugin_interface::Result<()> {
        match transaction {
            ReplicaTransactionInfoVersions::V0_0_1(transaction_info) => {
                info!("[notify_transaction V0_0_1], transaction:{:#?}, slot:{:#?}", transaction_info.is_vote, slot);
            }
            ReplicaTransactionInfoVersions::V0_0_2(transaction_info) => {
                if !transaction_info.is_vote {
                    info!("[notify_transaction V0_0_2], transaction:{:#?}, slot:{:#?}", transaction_info, slot);
                }
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    }

And I keep getting logs like:
[2024-04-10T15:44:54.361553499Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_scaffold::geyser_plugin_hook] [notify_transaction V0_0_2], transaction:ReplicaTransactionInfoV2 {
signature: 3SJJFMPTKohv5CBNQSfpJCPHGcMKZdANxZqWeo1pH9k9gWNe2XraK9ghpYiXoCjHYKMED8gpmNfTyH8ccCWPqVgA,
is_vote: false,
......
index: 1098,
}, slot:259368551

which is from 2 hours ago.
